# error in resource configuration of query expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: angularjs, node.js

i tried all methods given in here but no luck. my service is:

```
angular.module('xx')

  .factory('Complaints', function($resource) {

  return $resource('/api/complaints');
  });
```

my controller is:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $alert, $location, $http, $rootScope,Complaints) {

    $scope.complaints= Complaints.query();
    console.log($scope.complaints);
    console.log(Complaints.query());
    });
```

I dont know what's wrong. this code worked initially but then next time went wrong. I had just included few references in app.js file. It surely is not the problem.

Comment: please specify the error returned

Comment: This is default for query:

    var res = $resource('/users', {}, {
      query: {method: 'GET', params:{}, isArray:true},
    });

So result should be array. If object is returned in http response, error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `query` method expects data in array format but somehow your server is responding the data as a object instead of an array, hence you are getting the error.

So either you need to change your server side code to return array instead of object or to change your angular code to expect an object.

To change your angular code:

```
angular.module('xx')
  .factory('Complaints', function($resource) {
      // override query method config
      return $resource('/api/complaints', {}, {query: {isArray: false}});
  });
```